# relationship between scalar product and tensor product

Tags: geometry, vectors, products

I've been thinking about different products of vectors and the relationships between them, but am bumping hard into the limits of my knowledge. I was wondering if anyone has any thoughts.

Given two (Euclidean) vectors **a** and **b**, we can define a scalar product **a**.**b** which gives a scalar of magnitude |**a**||**b**|cos t where t is angle between them.

We can also define a tensor product **ab** whereby we get a matrix whose (ij)th element is the product of the ith element of **a** and the jth element of **b**, i.e. (**ab**)_ij =a_i b_j.

We know that if **a** and **b** are perpendicular then **a**.**b**=0 and also that Tr(**ab**)=0.

It seems ike there should be more statement like this which connect the two products, but I am a bit stuck as to what they might be. Does anyone have any thoughts or could anyone point me at some further reading on this?

Many thanks.

Comment: In general, $\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} = \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b})$.  I'm not sure there's more to say.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if $\mathbf a\otimes\mathbf b$ denotes the tensor product, i.e.
$$
(\mathbf a\otimes\mathbf b)_{ij}:=a_i b_j,
$$
then
$$
\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b=\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i=\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf a\otimes\mathbf b)_{ii}=\mathrm{Tr} (\mathbf a\otimes\mathbf b)
$$